# Avoid overriding data in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I would like to add multiple dictionary to NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSDictionary<NSString*,id<MGLAnnotation>>* feature = @{ localRef :     pointAnnotation };
[self.selectedFeatures setDictionary:feature];
```

I have initialised selectedFeatures NSMutableDictionary in ViewDidLoad of my view controller. I have written these above two lines of code in one function and that function will be called many times and the value of feature will always changing. I want to add those multiple feature to my selectedFeatures NSMUtableDictionary. But setDictionary just overridden the previous values. Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your `self.selectedFeatures` is an `NSMutableDictionary`. If you just want to add the `feature` dictionary to the `self.selectedFeatures`, then you can use the method `[NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
[self.selectedFeatures setDictionary:feature];
```

to this:

```
[self.selectedFeatures addEntriesFromDictionary:feature];
```